# Is creating an MVC model for a web module redundant?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller

In HTML/JS if you design a module of some sort with MVC, does the model become redundant if the view is driving the data?

**Example**

Suppose you have two forms on a screen; perhaps you are entering some soccer players into a team. For whatever reason, they cannot have the same name. Do you compare based on the DOM (view), or do you compare based on a constantly updating model which the view is controlling? I ask this because it is easily possible to miss a call to update the model. Perhaps there is a more generic way to always keep the model up to date.

```
class Form {
  constructor($form) {
    let self = this;
    this.$name = $form.find('[name="name"]');
    this.$age = $form.find('[name="age"]');

    // is this redundant? see FormManager..
    this.formData = new FormData();
    this.$name.on('input', function() {
      self.formData.name = $(this).val();
    });
    this.$age.on('input', function() {
      self.formData.age = $(this).val();
    });
  }
}

class FormData {
  constructor() {
    this.name = "";
    this.age = 0;
  }
}

class FormManager {
  constructor() {
      this.forms = {};
    }
    // could be done like this, from the model
    // but that means model must be updated
  validateFormsA() {
      let names = [];
      let valid = true;
      $.each(this.forms, function(i, e) {
        names.push(e.formData.name);
      });
      $.each(this.forms, function(i, e) {
        if ($.inArray(e.formData.name, names) > -1) {
          valid = false;
          return false;
        }
      })
      return valid;
    }

    // or like this, from the view
    // where the data is always 100% valid
  validateFormsB() {
    let names = [];
    let valid = true;
    $.each(this.forms, function(i, e) {
      names.push(e.$name.val());
    });
    $.each(this.forms, function(i, e) {
      if ($.inArray(e.$name.val(), names) > -1) {
        valid = false;
        return false;
      }
    })
    return valid;
  }
}
```

Comment: People have been dealing with this issue for a long time. I'd suggest looking into unidirectional data flow (Facebooks Flux pattern and more specifically the Redux library are implementations of it). With the method you mentioned, there is a problem with the model getting out of sync with the view. Unidirectional data flow addresses this problem by stating that all data comes from the "model" and any changes to it cause the view to completely re-render (with some smart diffing, preferably)

Comment: How can a model drive the view in when the view is actually the controller (user input) ?

Comment: By treating your UI like it's a function call. Like I said, do some reading on unidirectional data flow.